# Binding Endpoints of a Bezier Segment or Line to other shapes in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, bezier

I am trying to create something like the UDK or Maya material editor http://www.google.com/search?q=udk+material+editor&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&biw=1144&bih=929 where two nodes can be connected by clicking and dragging one connection to another. WPF *can* do this, but I don't know how to programatically (with C#, not XAML) bind the endpoints and control points of a bezier curve to follow the two node connections around. There are flow charts out there made with WPF, but none that have really helped (especially the free ones.)

Thanks for any help. It is much, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is for the object that contains the data representing the end points to have a property getter that returns a Geometry (with the bezier representation of the data)

Then bind the Data DependencyProperty of a Path object to that property,

Then when the points change, simply raise a PropertyChanged event (your object need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged) which will cause the binding to be updated,

This will cause a get on the Geometry property which can then return a new Geometry representing the current values in the object.

Comment: I'll try this and post back later today. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up not doing binding, instead I re-iterate through my list of beziers and reset the data each time. It may or may not be as efficient, but it's much easier. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I've certainly used that approach too!